# IE10 height:auto issue on first load

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-10

I wrote a small gallery thing that when a thumb is clicked, we use JS to create `new Image()`'s and replace the main image out with the full version of the chosen image.

I have a strange issue in IE10 when trying to auto-scale those main images within their containers. Upon first load, my images are stretched way too tall, but after they've loaded for the first time (cached), and we ask to render them again, the heights are perfectly fine.

I'm not setting the height with javascript, just CSS:

```
#flikr-gallery-image-main {
    min-height:300px;
}

#flikr-gallery-image-main img {
    width:100%!important;
    height:auto!important;
}
```

Here you can see the image stretched:

[image]

Once you choose other thumbs, then come back to this first thumb (again with a `new Image()`), it's height renders perfectly. What would cause IE10 to get "stuck" with blowing the height up on first source load?

Here's the relevant part of my javascript that loops through images in an array of images, creates thumbs, and sets the click action on those thumbs. The first time an image is .html()'d into the container, its way huge. The second and beyond is sized correctly.

```js
for( var i in flikr.photos )
{
    var thumb = new Image();
    $(thumb)
        .attr({
            'title':flikr.photos[i].title
        })
        .css({
            'cursor':'pointer'
        })
        .click(function()
        {
            var index = $(this).index();
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = flikr.photos[index].image_url;
            $('#flikr-gallery-image-main').html( img );
        });

    thumb.src = flikr.photos[i].thumbnail_url;

    $('#flikr-gallery-strip-thumbs').append( $(thumb) );
}
```

Comment: I should see codes please paste your codes here and/or put a fiddle here.

Comment: i updated my question with the relevant JS. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I hope it helps.

```
for( var i in flikr.photos )
{
    var $thumb = $('<img/>'); 
    $thumb
        .attr({
            'title':flikr.photos[i].title,
            'src':flikr.photos[i].thumbnail_url
        })
        .css({
            'cursor':'pointer'
        })
        .click(function()
        {
            var index = $(this).index();
            var $img = $('<img/>');
            $img.prop('src',flikr.photos[index].image_url);
            $('#flikr-gallery-image-main').html( $img );
        });

    $('#flikr-gallery-strip-thumbs').append($thumb);
}
```

I could not understand what is the exact problem is it when you want to create an image (onclick) on images' click?

Comment: awesome! that worked. thank you. the issue was the sizing / proportional scaling that i wanted to occur when dropping the main image into the container after a thumb is clicked. The first time the image is loaded, IE10 blew the height of the main image way too high. But, after subsequent requests to render the image again, it looked fine. I guess using jQuery to create the new DOM element vs natively works better in IE10 for some reason.

Comment: your missing a single quote on ```var $thumb = $('<img/>);```, SO wouldn't let me edit that for you, but this solution worked.

Comment: Yes jQuery is cross browser so when you had loaded jQuery in your web page its better to use its abilities.